# Can't detect QR code from ndarray, but can get information by scanning it with my phone

Tags: python, opencv, qr-code

I have a binary string which is converted from a QR code and its length is 29*29.

And I turned it into a ndarray. When I draw the ndarray with matplotlib, I can get the information by scanning it with my phone.

When I use [QRCodeDetector().detectAndDecode()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/de/dc3/classcv_1_1QRCodeDetector.html#a7290bd6a5d59b14a37979c3a14fbf394), however, I get nothing.

Perhaps it is because the qrcode is too small?

Here are some details:

```py
s = """111111101011011000000011111111000001010010001100010
1000001101110101111001010100010111011011101001100000111010
1011101101110100101000101010010111011000001010010100010000
1000001111111101010101010101011111110000000010111001111100
0000000001110101000000100000111001111010110101101100011010
1011101001000111011000010010001100101001110111111101111110
1010001010111101011100001011101001110101000001001010100101
1010011111001100111110010000101001100100000100110010011101
0110010101000110000010000000101011001000110100110111000000
1010000101000100011011010001010100001011100001111001000011
0010000100011100010010111111111111000000000011100101000110
0011001111111100000100110111010111101000001001001101101010
0010001101110101111010010001111111101011101010101000011001
0100000101110101101011101000110101101000001000110111010101
001001011111110011011100001011001100"""

gray = [int(i)*255 for i in s if i.isdigit()]
gray = np.array(gray)
gray = gray.reshape(29, 29)
gray = np.pad(gray, 1, "constant", constant_values=0)

gray = np.uint8(gray)
detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(gray)
print(data) 
print(bbox)

plt.imshow(gray, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

The output:

```py
None
```

But when I scan the QRCode with my phone, I can get:

```
[27877, 22434, 20102]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much!

**Updated**

I tried to enlarge the QRcode and pad it with a white or black background, but it didn’t work.

```py
gray = [int(i)*255 for i in s if i.isdigit()]
gray = np.array(gray)
gray = gray.reshape(29, 29)
gray = np.pad(gray, 1, "constant", constant_values=0)

w, h = gray.shape
gray = np.uint8(gray)
gray = cv2.resize(gray, (w*3, h*3), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
gray = np.pad(gray, 100, "constant", constant_values=255)

detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(gray)
print(data) 
print(bbox)

plt.imshow(gray, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

Comment: When you scan the QR with your phone, is it surrounded by a white background?

Comment: Yes, the QR has a white background. I also tried a black background, and the QR can still scanned by phone to get information.

Comment: What’s the “background“ when you “scan” the `gray` image? You pad with one pixel, is that enough for `detectAndDecode` to work?

Comment: @barny In fact, `gray` is an entire QR code, and it has no background. Thank you for reminding me, I tried to enlarge the QRcode and pad it with a white or black background, but it didn’t work.

Comment: @barny Please look at the **updated** content, this is my way of padding.